# Use RSVG as default delegate ImageMagick Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick

I need to be using RSVG delegate for my conversions.

```
convert -list format | grep SVG
 MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
  SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.3)
 SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.3)


identify -list delegate | grep "svg =" 
        svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"
```

Any ideas how to set it to the default for convert?

Comment: The `-list format` shows IM's internal SVG renderer, but the `-list delegate` shows that any `svg` request will be handled by `rsvg-convert`. So I would assume that RSVG _is_ already the default handler for svg images. You can verify by running `convert -debug All input.svg output.png | grep rsvg`

Comment: The grep didnt work but at least i can look through the debug . although its to long and unable to put it to a file . Seems silly to me

Comment: I am facing same issue . Its only showing in delegate list. noT IN FORMAT.

Comment: I am unable to convert svg properly

Comment: Easiest solution is to install Inkscape and ImageMagick will use it automatically. It is also better than RSVG.

Answer (score 10):

I made it work like this:

- install RSVG on your system
- configure and install ImageMagick from source with option `--with-rsvg=yes`

find more details here:
https://gist.github.com/maxivak/1476f7e979879da9f75371a86d5627b5

1. check imagemagick's support for svg

```
identify -list configure | grep svg
```

you should see something like this

```
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS  --disable-deprecated  --with-quantum-depth=16  --with-jemalloc=no  --with-umem=no  --with-autotrace=no  --with-gslib=no  --with-fontpath=  --with-rsvg=no  --with-perl=no
```

!NOTE! `--with-rsvg=no` which means that ImageMagick couldn't find rsvg in your system.

2. install RSVG

```
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

check rsvg works

```
rsvg-convert my.svg > my.png
```

3. reinstall imagemagick from source with option '--with-rsvg=no'

```
# download
wget https://imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz

# untar
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz

# 
cd ImageMagick-7.0.8

# !!! IMPORTANT. option `--with-srvg=yes` !!!

./configure --with-rsvg=yes

#
make

sudo make install

sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

4. verify the ImageMagick install worked properly with SVG

```
/usr/local/bin/identify my.svg
```

Comment: This helps when using command-line conversion. However, Imagick PHP library keeps using msvg and not rsvg. Anyone got it working for when converting through php’s Imagick?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem on how to use rsvg with the Imagick PHP library, @Meglio